# Adding Sound and Input Sound on Media Foundation Sink Writer

Tags: c#, audio, ms-media-foundation, sharpdx

I'm able to produce mp4 file with my screen recording app but it only captures screen and has no sound. Now I want it to also make the recording output an audio. What I want is to encode the audio that is coming from the pc which is the direct sound and blend it with the sound that coming from the mic. I'm using sharpdx and mediafoundation.net Below is my code how I initialize the audiodevice in sharpdx

```
        var audioDevices = SharpDX.DirectSound.DirectSoundCapture.GetDevices();
        SharpDX.DirectSound.DirectSound dxSoundCapture = new SharpDX.DirectSound.DirectSound(audioDevices.First().DriverGuid);
```

and below is how I initialize the mediatype for the audio in mediafoundation

```
    IMFMediaType audioTypeIn = null;
IMFMediaType audioTypeOut = null;

// Create the Audio input type 
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)MFExtern.MFCreateMediaType(out audioTypeOut);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)audioTypeOut.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType.Audio);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)audioTypeOut.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFMediaType.AAC);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)audioTypeOut.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, 2);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)audioTypeOut.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, 44100);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)audioTypeOut.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, 16);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)audioTypeOut.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, 1);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)sinkWriter.AddStream(audioTypeOut, out streamAudIndex);

// Create the Audio input type 
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)MFExtern.MFCreateMediaType(out audioTypeIn);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)audioTypeIn.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType.Audio);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)audioTypeIn.SetGUID(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFMediaType.PCM);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)audioTypeIn.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, 2);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)audioTypeIn.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, 44100);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)audioTypeIn.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, 16);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)audioTypeIn.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, 1);
if (Succeeded(hr)) hr = (int)sinkWriter.SetInputMediaType(streamAudIndex, audioTypeIn, null);
```

My question is how can I supply the audio sample to my sinkwriter? In my video I basically supply the texture2d coming from SharpDX and make a sample buffer out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You are preparing Sink Writer to accept a PCM audio stream of the following configuration: 44100 samples/sec, stereo, 16 bits/sample.

You are supposed to either obtain media samples with respective data, or create them yourself using `MFCreateSample` and friends. See also [Working with Media Samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530106) on MSDN.

Once you have a media sample, [`IMFSinkWriter::WriteSample`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374654) sends it to encoding.

Comment: Creating memory buffer will increase the cpu usage of my app. I would like to know if its possible to provide directly the sounds to the sinkwriter without memory buffer just like what I did in my texture2d. I used MFCreateVideoSampleFromSurface to create sample and MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer to get mediabuffer and write it to the sinkwriter

Comment: You should not worry about this, really. It is not even video vs. audio aspect here, but the fact of software encoding and your consumption through SharpDX with its overhead make turn `MFCreateSample` into nearly zero expense call.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I don't know how to pass the data from my device to sink. is there an easy way to do that in media foundation?

Comment: Hi Roman, I've been searching on the internet and i was so surprise that the reference I was looking for was this website. alax.info and I saw that you were the author.  I saw one of your article which is http://alax.info/blog/1716 I believed that the application is written using C++ and was capable of capturing audio.  The source is not available on your site and I'm wondering if you have plan on releasing it for educational purposes. this is my email by the way. gvon18@yahoo.com Thanks

Comment: The code was repurposed for another project, so source code is not available. Sorry for this!

Comment: oh I see. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Roman, I'm sorry to bother you again but it is regarding with your blog post here alax.info/blog/1716. Your application stop recording when I run application that goes in full screen. Do you have idea how to record also the screen when I run some application in full screen mode? Thanks

Comment: @kripto: just start another Desktop Duplication session in a while and you get the video stream again. Putting it smoother into the same continuous file is more complicated but also possible if you develop respective gluing layer between Desktop Duplication and MF Media Sink.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I already tried that. But I'm still getting Device was lost. I'm using D3DSurface and pass it to Sinkwriter. I also tried re initilizing my D3D device when it detects that the device was lost but my recording stop.

Comment: This is thesame error I'm encountering. https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/issues/798

Comment: Hi Roman, You are right now I can record in full screen mode but it creates another file, My recording now creates new file everytime it switch to fulscreen and non fullscreen. I'm now figuring out how is the gluing part or do you have any idea to continue the recording without having multiple files created.

Comment: @kripto: you decide when to start a new file. As long as you use the same `IMFSinkWriter` instance, you keep doing the same file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. By the way I'm using attributes.SetUnknown(MFAttributesClsid.MF_SINK_WRITER_D3D_MANAGER, m_pDeviceManager); and my problem here is after going to fullscreen the d3ddevice will be reinitialize to make the duplicateOutput work again and I don't know how can I bound the new d3dManager to the IMFSinkwriter again.

Comment: Hi Roman, Is there a way I can copy resource of texture2d to another texture2d with diferrent width and height? like this d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(originalTexture2d, resizedTexture2d); Because I need to have a consistent size of texture2d before passing it to the sinkwriter.